# Selecting a list of elements based on a descendant element NOT containing a particular value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to select a list of elements based on a value that appears nested deep within the element I need to select. This value may or may not contain a key phrase, and if it does, I need to ignore that element but continue getting the rest.

I've been through various examples I've found on here but none have seemed to work. I believe I'm on the right track but have messed up my XPath somewhere along the way. I need to compile a list of all of the 'entry' elements whose descendant 'reference' does not contain 'fakeResult' as part of its value. I know my XPath works to get a list of all 'entry' elements, but beyond that it stops working and completely errors out.

```
<xsl:variable name="results" select="//code[@code='XXX']/ancestor::section/entry[organizer/component/observation/text/reference[not(contains(@value, 'fakeResult']]"/>
```

Comment: Please provide a **reproducible** example, including the input XML - see: [mcve]. Also, if you get an error, post the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to compile a list of all of the 'entry' elements whose
>   descendant 'reference' does not contain 'fakeResult' as part of its
>   value.

From your expression I think you mean the attribute named `value` when you write about `reference`' value. With that in mind:

```
//entry[not(.//reference[contains(@value,'fakeResult')])]
```